# In the perspective of runtime performance, is Docker running on cloud services efficient?

Tags: docker

Well known cloud services provide Docker Container service. But they provide Containers running on virtual machines. They charge nothing to Docker Containers, but they charge for virtual machines which run them.

Docker Containers are faster for runtime performance compared to virtual machines, but slower than physical machines. It is known that the computation performance is almost same to physical server, but the network performance is about 70% of real machine. So the performance strength in Docker is meaningful only for running physical Container hosts. In short, a Docker Containers running on virtual machines is slower than the virtual machine itself, so it is useless to run Docker Container on cloud services as long as the cloud services provide Docker Containers in their virtual machines.

Of course, I know that it is unavoidable because Docker Containers is not as sandbox-secure as virtual machines. Then, what is the benefit of using Docker if we consider only the runtime performance?

Comment: What's the source for the network performance?

Comment: page 94 at http://www.slideshare.net/modestjude/dockerat-deview-2013

Comment: That's 3 years old. Docker has changed drastically since then. The stats I have read lately show that there is something like 2% penalty in running on in a docker container as opposed to running directly on the host. Sorry, I didn't keep a link of the article. As for networking, there is a penalty if you're running an overlay network, but that's not a docker limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that presentation is a bit old and brief in the performance section to be used as a reference for Docker performance. I can't see much setup detail on the benchmarks that were done (it might be in Korean?). Maybe try some more detailed research or recent bench marks.

http://blog.pierreroudier.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/rc25482.pdf

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/08/03/testing-docker-multi-host-network-performance/

http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-with-docker-performance-characteristics/

Yes, there can be some network degradation in containers depending on your use case, most of which can be worked around. I certainly don't think it makes Docker containers "useless", especially when so much of a container runs at close to host speed.

One thing that I can't see any reference to in any NAT benchmarks is if they have tried disabling the Docker userland proxy `--userland-proxy=false` which you don't want to be using if you are trying to push the network via mapped ports (the standard way to connect to a Docker container).

> Then, what is the benefit of using Docker if we consider only the
>   runtime performance?

Containers and Virtual Machines don't exist for run time performance. They exist so you can divide up your physical hosts into smaller and/or more easily managed partitions. If only runtime performance was considered then manufacturing custom ASIC's to run an application would be the way to go, but it very rarely is the way in the real world.

You can certainly get more out of your hardware if you run containers directly on a physical host rather than with a VM. Docker still presents enough packaging and management benefits for people to want to use it on a virtual machine, even with the small amount of additional overhead.